# Find most occurring sums of 3 vectors with n elements of type int

Tags: c++

I have n vectors with k elements of type int. How can I find the most occurring sum when summing up all combinations of elements contained in these n vectors?

Currently working on a sample with 3 vectors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::vector<int> x;
    std::vector<int> y;
    std::vector<int> mostCommon;
    int inputV;
    int inputX;
    int inputY;

    std::cout << "Enter values for vector v: ";
    while (std::cin >> inputV)
    {
       v.push_back(inputV);
    }
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::cout << "Enter values for vector x: ";
    while (std::cin >> inputX)
    {
       x.push_back(inputX);
    }
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::cout << "Enter values for vector y: ";
    while (std::cin >> inputY)
    {
       y.push_back(inputY);
    }

    std::vector<int> possibleSums;

    for( int vE : v )
        for( int xE : x )
            for( int yE : y )
                possibleSums.push_back( vE + xE + yE );

    std::sort( possibleSums.begin(), possibleSums.end() );
    std::set<int> possibleSumSet( possibleSums.begin(), possibleSums.end() );

    int mostCommonCount = 0;
    for( int sum : possibleSumSet )
    {
        int count = std::count( possibleSums.begin(), possibleSums.end(), sum );
        if( count >= mostCommonCount )
        {
            mostCommonCount = count;
            mostCommon.push_back (sum);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Most Common Sum Range: " << int(mostCommon.size()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Most Common Sums: ";
    for (auto i = mostCommon.begin(); i != mostCommon.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "Most Common Count: " << mostCommonCount;
}
```

---

Sample Input for vectors:

`Enter values for vector v: 1 2 4 5`
`Enter values for vector x: 1 2 3`
`Enter values for vector y: 2 3`

Possible sums for aboves sample input:

```
1+1+2=4  
1+1+3=5  
1+2+2=5  
2+1+2=5  
1+2+3=6  <-  
1+3+2=6  <-  
2+1+3=6  <-  
2+2+2=6  <-  
1+3+3=7  <-   
2+2+3=7  <-  
2+3+2=7  <-  
4+1+2=7  <-  
2+3+3=8  <-  
4+1+3=8  <-  
4+2+2=8  <-  
5+1+2=8  <-  
4+2+3=9  <-  
4+3+2=9  <-  
5+1+3=9  <-  
5+2+2=9  <-   
4+3+3=10  
5+2+3=10  
5+3+2=10  
5+3+3=11
```

So the results here would be:

- Most Common Sum Range: 4
- Most Common Sums: 6, 7, 8, 9
- Most Common Count: 4

What I currently get is:

```
Most Common Sum Range: 6                                                                                                    
Most Common Sums: 4 5 6 7 8 9                                                                                               
Most Common Count: 4
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just loop the largest vector, looping each smaller vector for each element of each vector, pushing them all the results to a new vector, and finding the most common i.e.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> x = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> y = { 2, 3 };

    std::vector<int> possibleSums;

    for( int vE : v )
        for( int xE : x )
            for( int yE : y )
                possibleSums.push_back( vE + xE + yE );

    std::sort( possibleSums.begin(), possibleSums.end() );
    std::set<int> possibleSumSet( possibleSums.begin(), possibleSums.end() );

    int mostCommon = 0, mostCommonCount = 0;
    for( int sum : possibleSumSet )
    {
        int count = std::count( possibleSums.begin(), possibleSums.end(), sum );
        if( count > mostCommonCount )
        {
            mostCommonCount = count;
            mostCommon = sum;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Most Common Sum: " << mostCommon 
              << "; Most Common Count: " << mostCommonCount;
}
```

Edit: You can also store off every highest occurring number into a `std::vector` so subsequent highest occurrences aren't ignored :

```
int mostCommonCount = 0;
std::vector<int> mostCommonSums;
for( int sum : possibleSumSet )
{
    int count = std::count( possibleSums.begin(), possibleSums.end(), sum );
    if( count > mostCommonCount )
    {
        mostCommonCount = count;
        mostCommonSums.clear();
        mostCommonSums.push_back( sum );
    }
    else if( count == mostCommonCount )
    {
        mostCommonSums.push_back( sum );
    }
}

for( int sum : mostCommonSums )
    std::cout << "Most Common Sum: " << sum << std::endl;

std::cout << "Most Common Count: " << mostCommonCount;
```

Comment: This seems to be the right approach but seems to return just the first most occurrence which here is 6 but missing out 7, 8 and 9 which occurs 4 times too.

Comment: @S.H. I've edited the post to account for that :).

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Make a list of all of the sums.

Step 2: Count how often each sum shows up.

Step 3: Return the one that shows up the most.

Each of these steps could be a function. I'll leave the implementation of them to you.